# Conservation of Mass in 2D

Tags: java, math, physics

I've got this program where balls bounce around the screen. I want the balls to be able to bounce them off each other.

So, I've got this
    `boolean intersects(ball b2) {. . .}`
method, it checks if b.intersects with b2. If b.intersects(x) returns true, then `calcDX()` and `calcDY()` are called.

```
void calcDX(Ball b2) {
    double b1Momentum = mass * dx;
    double b2Momentum = b2.mass * b2.dx;

    double b2FinalVelocity = (b1Momentum + b2Momentum + mass * (dx + b2.dx)) / (mass + b2.mass);

    dx = b2FinalVelocity - dx - b2.dx;
    b2.dx = b2FinalVelocity; //hi
}

void calcDY(Ball b2) {
    double b1Momentum = mass * dy;
    double b2Momentum = b2.mass * b2.dy;

    double b2FinalVelocity = (b1Momentum + b2Momentum + mass * (dy + b2.dy)) / (mass + b2.mass);

    dy = b2FinalVelocity - dy - b2.dy;
    b2.dy = b2FinalVelocity;
}
```

So this is the equation for elastic collisions that I'm using, where `dx` and `dy` is the change in `x` and the change in `y`.

So I've got this loop (I know, `while(true)`, ignore it.) that updates 60 times in a second that calls `updateBallPositions()` each time

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int ticksPerSecond = 60;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double nanoSecondsPerTick = 1000000000.0 / ticksPerSecond; // How many nano-seconds in a tick
    double delta = 0.0;

    while (true) {  // main game loop
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / nanoSecondsPerTick;
        lastTime = now;

        while (delta >= 1) { // tick
            delta -= 1;

            updateBallPositions();
            f.panel.repaint();
        }
    }
}

private void updateBallPositions() {
    for (Ball b : balls) {
        b.x += b.dx;
        b.y += b.dy;

        for (Ball b2 : balls) {
            if(b != b2 & b.intersects(b2)) {
                b.calcDX(b2);
                b.calcDY(b2);
            }
        }

        if(b.isTouchingHorizontalWall(f))
            b.dy *= -1;
        if(b.isTouchingVerticalWall(f))
            b.dx *= -1;
    }
}
```

All this is great but it doesn't work. The balls often get stuck together and collide forever, while it should be allowing the balls to bounce smoothly. (If you need more code, say so)

Comment: "If you need more code, say so" I think you do :  "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_."

Comment: How can you attempt to solve this problem without knowing anything about the physics?

Comment: I believe that this is more of a code issue. I THINK that since the momentum changes, there isn't enough time for the ball to move out of the 'intersecting zone' of the ball it was previously intersecting.

If this is the case, then 2 balls could get stuck together forever, which does happen.

Comment: Collision is a non-linear problem.  I'm certain that your limited understanding of the physics means you aren't solving the problem correctly.  If your time steps are too big your bodies will move past the collision zone and it'll never be detected.

Answer (score 1):

Your collision treatment looks wrong.

Let ball `A` has mass `ma`, velocity vector `VA0`
Let ball `B` has mass `mb`, velocity vector `VB0`
They collide at point `C`
To calculate velocities after collision, we must use law of сonservation of energy and law of сonservation of momentum

Consider temporary axes:
`T` -  tangential to both balls through point `C`  and radial `R` connecting ball centers

[image]

Projections of velocities onto `T` are tangential vectors (for example, `VAt`), onto axis `R` are radial vectors  (for example, `VAr`)

Important - tangential momentums don't change during collision: `VAt1=VAt, VBt1=VBt`

So we have equations in `T-R` coordinate system

```
 ma * VAr + mb * VBr = ma * VAr1 + mb * VAr2
 ma * VA0^2 + mb*VB0^2 = ma * VA1^2 + mb*VB1^2   // I removed division by two
 but
 VA1^2 = VAr1^2 + VAt^2
 VB1^2 = VBr1^2 + VBt^2
```

so finally system of two equations with two unknowns `VAr1, VBr1`

```
 ma * VAr + mb * VBr = ma * VAr1 + mb * VAr2
 ma * VA0^2 + mb*VB0^2 = ma * (VAr1^2 + VAt^2) + mb*(VBr1^2 + VBt^2)
```

Solve it, transform velocity components into world coordinate system `OXY`

Comment: Sorry, not understanding this (Probably because I haven't taken physics classes yet). Which equation is which, and how do I apply them.